# How do I move an Option from one structure field to another, keeping both structures?

Tags: rust

I would like to move the value of one struct's field to another struct like this:

```
struct MyStruct {
    value1: Option<Vec<usize>>,
    value2: i32,
    // ...,
}

impl MyStruct {
    pub fn child(&mut self, value2: i32) -> MyStruct {
        let mut value1 = self.value1.unwrap();

        // Do some stuff..

        MyStruct {
            value1: Some(value1),
            value2: value2,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut first = MyStruct {
        // Building the first structure
        value1: Some((0..10).map(|_| 0).collect()),
        value2: 0,
    };

    // Using it

    let second = first.child(1);
}
```

I get an error:

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of borrowed content
 --> src/main.rs:9:26
  |
9 |         let mut value1 = self.value1.unwrap();
  |                          ^^^^ cannot move out of borrowed content
```

How can I tell Rust to move `value1` from the first instance to the second, leaving `value1` of first equal to `None`?

Later in my code I need to go back to potentially all the instances I used, reading other values but not the vector.

I used to do a copy of the field but since I'm exploring a graph that is really huge, memory can't take it and it's not very efficient.

Comment: [`Option.take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.take)?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [E_net4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1233251/e-net4) I found an easy way of doing it :

```
pub fn child(&mut self, value2: i32) -> MyStruct {
    MyStruct {
        value1: self.value1.take(),
        value2: value2,
    }
}
```

Here, `value1: self.value1.take()` moves the value1 content from `self` to the new structure, leaving `None` in `self.value1`.